# Use of undeclared type 'KeychainAccess'

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm trying to use the KeychainAccess pod at:
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

However, when I import it I get this error:

[image: Error]

KeychainAccess is showing up in Purple and I see it in my Pods target as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keychainAccess` isn't of type `KeychainAccess`, it's a `Keychain`:

```
private let keychainAccess: Keychain = {
    return Keychain(service: "com.startbox")
}()
```

KeychainAccess isn't a type, it's a module.

It also may not be necessary to make your keychain a computed property.

```
private let keychainAccess = Keychain(service: "com.startbox")
```